# endecaQuery method to disable any query parameter

Tags: endeca

I have a endecaQuery in which I have Rollup parameter added. I need to remove the rollup parameter/disable. Now this is required only for one scenario so I cannot remove it completely. Any endecaQuery method available through which I can disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [ENEQuery API](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29584_01/PresentationAPIJava/navigation/com/endeca/navigation/ENEQuery.html).

Method that sets the roll up key is setNavRollupKey()

Comment: I mean i would use set get methods to change the rollup key acording to the case.